# Call a method periodically without using Runnable and Timer class

Tags: java, android, timer, runnable

I was wondering if it is possible to have a periodically call of a method, without using Runnable and Timer class. In a few words, how to call a method without creating a new thread at all?
Thank you.

Comment: yes that's called alarmmanager.

Comment: Why do you want such a thing ?

Comment: Just think about that a bit more. calling something periodically will involve a lot of repeated waiting. During which time your main thread can't do anything else, including servicing key presses etc. That's why network activity must be done on a separate thread to avoid locking up the main app thread.

Comment: use a Handler, it doesnt create any Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to have a periodically call of a method, without using Runnable and Timer class

While you can avoid a `Timer`, you are going to need *something* that is going to be triggered on this periodic basis.

For example, you could have a `Runnable` that does work, then calls `postDelayed()` on any `View` (or a `Handler`) to schedule itself to run again in the future:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed))

Answer (score 0):

Since AlarmManager has been mentioned, You could use a JobScheduler if you are targetting API level 21 and above (an AlarmManager should be used for lower level APIs):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo)

> This is an API for scheduling various types of jobs against the
>   framework that will be executed in your application's own process.
>
> The framework will be intelligent about when you receive your
>   callbacks, and attempt to batch and defer them as much as possible.
>   Typically if you don't specify a deadline on your job, it can be run
>   at any moment depending on the current state of the JobScheduler's
>   internal queue, however it might be deferred as long as until the next
>   time the device is connected to a power source.
>
> You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, retrieve it
>   through Context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE).

`JobService`'s `schedule` method requires a `JobInfo` which can configure periodic delays.

An example:

```
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(getContext(), YourService.class);

        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(SERVICE_INTERVAL);
        //pass data to your service here.
        builder.setExtras(bundle);

        JobScheduler jobScheduler = getContext().getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```